# pdfcrop command with shell escape magic comment not working in TeXstudio

Tags: xetex, texstudio, shell-escape

I would like to use `pdfcrop` to get a tight crop of [this table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/316605/98306) (credit to Bernard) from my other question.

I want to execute `pdfcrop` every time the document is compiled, so I have included at the end of the document the command `\immediate\write18{pdfcrop table.pdf}`, where `table.pdf` is the name of the pdf that is generated after the source code is compiled.

Since I am using TeXstudio, I have added the following magic comments at the top of the document:

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///xelatex/[--shell-escape]
```

The first magic comment tells TeXstudio to compile the document with `xelatex`, and the second magic comment is supposed to enable the shell escape interaction, as explained in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99601/98306).

However, when I run the code, I only get the original table but not the cropped table. So this tells me that there might be something that is preventing the execution of the `\immediate\write18{pdfcrop table.pdf}` command. But I get no errors or warnings.

What am I missing?

**Note:** I run Windiws 8.1 and have MiKTeX, Ghostscript and the ActiveState distribution of Perl installed in my machine.

---

Here is the source code. It compiles with `xelatex` only. Please make sure that you save the source code as `table.tex`.

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///xelatex/[--shell-escape]
% !TeX spellcheck = en_GB

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{array, tabularx, arydshln}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{pst-node, multido}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\usepackage{layouts}

\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}(-8.6,-8)(10,6)
        \sffamily\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.8}\centering
        \fontsize{10.5}{13}\selectfont
        \psset{linecolor=red}
        \rput(0,0){\begin{tabularx}{1.2\textwidth}{|*{12}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}}
                \multicolumn{12}{c}{TITLE} \\
                \hline
                \multicolumn{12}{|c|}{SOME INFORMATION} \\
                \hline
                \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{GROUP 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{GROUP 2} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{GROUP 3} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{GROUP 4} \\
                A & B & A & B & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{C} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{D} & & & & \\
                AA & AA & BB & BB & CC & DD & AA & BB & EE & FF & GG & HH \\
                \hline
                10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 \\
                9 & 9 & 9 & 9 & 9 & 9 & 9 & 9 & 9 & 9 & 9 & 9 \\
                8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & \circlenode{c9}{8} & 8 & 8 & 8 \\
                \hdashline
                7 & 7 & 7 & 7 & 7 & 7 & 7 & 7 & 7 & \circlenode{c10}{7} & 7 & 7 \\
                6 & \circlenode{c2}{6} & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 \\
                \rnode{R1}{5} & \rnode{R2}{5} & \rnode{R3}{5} & \rnode{R4}{5} & \rnode{R5}{5} & \rnode{R6}{5} & \rnode{R7}{5} & \rnode{R8}{5} & \rnode{R9}{5} & \rnode{R10}{5} & \rnode{R11}{\circlenode{c11}{5}} & \rnode{R12}{5} \\
                \circlenode{c1}{4} & 4 & 4 & 4 &\circlenode{c5}{4} & 4 & \rnode{t7}{4} & \circlenode{c8}{4} & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 \\
                3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & \rnode{b7}{3} & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
                \hdashline
                2 & 2 & \circlenode{c3}{2} & \circlenode{c4}{2} & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & \circlenode{c12}{2} \\
                1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \circlenode{c6}{1} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
                0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
                \hline
            \end{tabularx}}
            \midAB(t7)(b7){m7}\rput(m7){\circlenode[framesep=0pt]{c7}{3,5}}%
            \multido{\ia=1+1, \ib=2+1}{11}{\ncline{c\ia}{c\ib}}
            \pnode[-0.85cm, 0](R1){R0}
            \pnode[0.85cm, 0](R12){R13}
            \psset{linewidth=0.5pt, linecolor=black, nodesep=3pt}
            \multido{\ia=0+1, \ib=1+1}{13}{\ncline{R\ia}{R\ib}}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
\immediate\write18{pdfcrop table.pdf}
```

Comment: Nothing is executed after `\end{document}` so put the line starting with `\immediate ....` before `\end{document}`. If still no go, check the log file `table.log` for the `runsystem` keyword and post the entire line here (it says if the shell command was executed or not).

Comment: @alwaysask I did as you said and it worked! But wait, that's not the end of the story. It only works when I click on the "Compile" button (table.log: `runsystem(pdfcrop table.pdf)...executed.`). But it doesn't work when I click on the "Build & View" button (table.log: `runsystem(pdfcrop table.pdf)...disabled (restricted).`). Is there an explanation for this?

Comment: Presumably build&view doesn't allow shell escape.

Comment: Remove or double comment `% !TeX program = xelatex` and it will work with "Build & View" as well.